# Why my redux store is not getting firebase email property? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux

I´m trying to do that when I login with firebase, i receive the user data in my Redux store.

When I **alert()** my email inside the **onAuthStateChanged** function i receive it, but when I try to alert my email from my other components I receive **undefined**

See, this is my onAuthState

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    store.dispatch({
  type: "USER_LOGIN",
  payload: { user: user.providerData[0] }
});
  } else {
    store.dispatch({ type: "USER_LOGOUT" });
  }
});
```

And this is my **redux store**

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "USER_LOGIN":
      return { ...state, logged: true };

    case "USER_LOGOUT":
      return { ...state, logged: false };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const initialState = {
  logged: null,
  user: []
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use any middleware like `redux-saga` or `redux-thunk` to handle side effect?

Comment: Nope, I don´t know about it

Answer (score 0):

Have you connect to redux from your other Component?

```
import React from 'react'
Import {connect} from 'react-redux'
...
class YourOtherComponent extends React.Component {

    state = {
         user: ''
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({user: this.props.user})
    }

    render(){

        return(

        <div>this.state.user</div>

        )
    }
}
mapStateToProps = state => ({
    user: state.user
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps )(YourOtherComponent)
```

Comment: Yes, I made it, I tried to console.log(this.props) in my component and I received my logged and the user, but without the data.

Comment: try to use `componentDidMount()` to set your state. I have updated the code

Comment: or `componentWiillRecieveProps(nextProps){ this.setState({user: nextProps.user})`

Comment: Bro, I think that the problem is here **case "USER_LOGIN":
      return { ...state, logged: true }; ** I´m not changing the user store data, only I send it with the payload